# Use Terraform to enabled AWS CodeBuild to push logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

AWS CodeBuild has an option in the UI to upload build output logs to CloudWatch and/or publish the logs to S3 but I do not see an option in Terraform to enable this feature through the "aws_codebuild_project" resource.

Here is a link to the Terraform docs:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html

Is there another way to possibly enable this feature via Terraform?

I can create a CloudWatch Event to capture CodeBuild events but that doesn't give me the full logs.

Answer (score 2):

So even thought the Terraform documentation does not specify support for enabling CloudWatch logs for CodeBuild jobs, if you create a CodeBuild job with the AWS CodeBuild Project resource it will by default enable that checkbox for you, at least as of the date of this answer.

The Cloudwatch log Log Group will be created with the following format: aws/codebuild/codebuild_project_name

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [PR](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/7534) for a Github [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6312) to enable CodeBuild CloudWatch logs, so hopefully we will be able to use the following config soon:

```
logs_config {
  cloudwatch_logs {
    status = "ENABLED|DISABLED"
    group_name = "..."
    stream_name = "..."
  }
}
```